# Update checkbox value in gridview using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, checkbox

Here is the part of html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="popunjen">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkStatus" runat="server" Checked='<%#Eval("status") %>' AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkStatus_CheckedChanged"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And here is the ado.net code behind:

```
protected void chkStatus_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (conn)
    {
        query = "UPDATE Seminari SET status=@status WHERE idSeminar=@idSeminar";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        conn.Open();
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvSeminari.Rows)
        {
            int idSeminar = Convert.ToInt32(gvSeminari.DataKeys [row.RowIndex].Values[0]);
            bool isSelected = (row.FindControl("chkStatus") as CheckBox).Checked;
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idSeminar", idSeminar);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", isSelected);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

I am working with this in another project where i am using entity framework. how can i update this field "popunjen" in gridview using entity.

Comment: I don't think you got stuck with the checkbox part, but rather putting any sort of Entity Framework calls in here at all. Is the problem not understanding how to use Entity Framework?

Comment: You need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries consistently. You have some code with parameters and others that are wide open to sql injection. You also need to be sure you specify the scale of your parameters. Varchar parameters default to 30, but when used as a variable varchar defaults to a length of 1. Safe yourself the anguish and be explicit.

Comment: This is just ***WAAAAAAAAAYYYYYYYY*** too much code! Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and trim down your huge pile of code to the **relevant pieces** for this question

Comment: Please consult the following page and go from there: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907 Explaning both how to set up Entity framework and translate your SQLCommand parameters to EF is a bit much to ask.

Comment: I highly recommend you read through [Best Practices - Executing Sql Statements](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/3589/ado-net/14261/best-practices-executing-sql-statements) to get a better understanding of how to use ADO.NET.